# What happen if a body travel with fast speed?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, inertial-frames, speed

Suppose a car is moving with high speed ( say 100km/hr ) Now, while moving with such speed is the mass of car going to change with respect to car at rest?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/44126

Answer (score 1):

It will increase by an incredibly small amount. Relativistic mass is given by,

$$ m = \frac{m_0}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}} $$

Where $m_0$ is the rest mass.

At such extremely low velocities relative to the speed of light, which is about 300 million meters per second, the mass will increase by an extremely small amount.

This will equate to approximately

$$ m = m_0 \left(1 + 4.3 \times 10^{-15}\right) $$

If the car weighs 2 tons, then the mass will increase by approximately 8 nanograms at this speed.

Comment: But how to experience that increase in mass??

Comment: Well. It will be too small to experience it or measure it experimentally. Some time dilation experiments have been successfully done on aircraft using cesium clocks.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele-Keating_experiment

Answer (score -2):

Yes its mass will increase as its speed increasesss. But your speed is too much less so only negligible amount of mass will increase.